# Why cant I see my embedded javascript with firebug?

Tags: firebug

Downloaded firebug and love it.

One problem though: can you view/debug script not found in .js files (i.e. html, cshtml, etc..) with firebug?

1). If i view source on the browser page I see my javascript (runs fine)

2). From firebug, the html tab just shows the html

3). From firebug, the script tab just shows the .js files.

I must be missing something basic... I would like to be able to set breakpoints, etc.. but can only find the scripts in .js files.

All advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have always been able to find the inline scripts in the Script panel.

A workaround would be, if you have access to the script, to write a "debugger;" statement there to force Firebug to halt where you want.